# Mapbox GL JS with self hosted vector tiles has missing levels?

Tags: layers, mapbox, zoom, mapbox-gl, vector-tiles

Using Mapbox GL JS with self hosted vector tiles in protobuf format where it looks for tiles using {z}/{x}/{y}.pb paths.

I have a scenario where I only have data for zoom levels 9, 11 and 13.

Is there any way to prevent Mapbox GL JS to try loading other zoom levels?

At the moment I get a bunch of 404's on zoom level 12 for example.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#new-mapboxgl-map-options-), there are `minZoom` and `maxZoom` options available `mapboxgl.Map` object.  Set these to 9 and 13 respectively and users won't be able to zoom beyond these points.

As for skipping zoom 10 and 12, you could listen to the [zoom event](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#new-mapboxgl-map-options--events), test whether the new zoom is 10 or 12, and force the map to skip to the next zoom.  *(I'm not sure what the zoom event looks like internally, but it must contain all the necessary data: previous zoom and new zoom.  Throw it up on a jsfiddle and I'll take a look)*

That being said, forcing users to skip a zoom level seems like bad UI.  I wouldn't recommend it unless there's really no way to generate tiles at zoom 10 and 12.